# Restoring backup with tar

Tags: backup, data-recovery, tar

hi i'am usin Ubuntu server 14.04
I want to backup all data in /mnt/backups/(pictures music etc.)
i use:

`tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz /mnt/backups/`

and i want recover into `/home/john/recover/`
i use:

```
tar –xvpzf backup.tar.gz –C /home/john/recover/
```

but then I recover in `/home/john/recover` it looks like:

```
/home/john/recover/mnt/backups/(and all my data,pictures music etc.)
```

Is there a way to make `/home/john/recover/(and all my data,pictures music etc.)`
or I do something wrong or its just what `tar` does? Thanks.
P.S. sorry for any spelling mistakes :))

Answer (score 1):

tar cares about your present working directory at invocation time.

What you want to do is:

```
cd /mnt/backups/
tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz *
cd /home/john/recover/
tar –xvpzf backup.tar.gz
```

Comment: still after recover i get mnt, i'am using tar with cron

Comment: I'd made a typo on the second line. Instead of specifying the full path, just a shellglob wildcard should be sufficient.

Comment: it worked with
tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz *
tar –xvpzf backup.tar.gz -C /home/john/restore

Comment: Awesome. I tested it here before posting, but had typed incorrectly. Sorry for the initial confusion.

Comment: sorry to bother you but is there a way to backup not being in same folder like cd /mnt/backups/
tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz *

but instead something like:
tar -cvpzf /testing/backup.tar.gz /mnt/backups/

Comment: The --file option can specify a file anywhere, so tar -cvpzf /testing/backup.tar.gz /mnt/backups/ will work, but you will get the /mnt/backups/ directory structure, because the files in the directory will always be archived relative to the working directory, and the directory will be re-created along with its contents when the archive is extracted. So if you don't want the /mnt/backups/ part, your script **must** change into that directory first, like: cd /mnt/backups/ && tar -cvpzf /testing/backup.tar.gz *